# How to block access to a set of url patterns by IP?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, silverstripe

I've been trying to block access to `/admin` and `/admin/{anything}` with /admin not being a physical sub directory in silverstripe except for a limited set of IP addresses and have come up with the following .htaccess file section which for the most part works.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase '/'

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?(admin/(.*)|admin)$
  RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(127\.0\.0\.1|216\.58\.208\.36)$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=403,L]

</IfModule>
```

However it was pointed out to me that this doesn't block the non-rewritten access `framework/main.php?url=admin` and `framework/main.php?url=admin/{anything}`

On top of this Silverstripe can also be served through Nginx which doesn't support .htaccess.

How can I update this .htaccess section to block the non-rewritten version as well, and also how would I do the same thing in nginx?

Comment: I suggest not asking 2 different questions in the same thread. `nginx` rules will be totally different from `mod_rewrite`. Stick to `mod_rewrite` rules in this one and once that is solved ask a new one for `nginx`

Answer (score 2):

Hailwood, there are a couple modules that touch on this. Might be a good starting point:

https://github.com/silverstripe-labs/silverstripe-securityextras

https://github.com/prij/silverstripe-iprestrictedpage

Comment: Hey muskie9, Cheers for the modules. Unfortunately they require booting up SS to do the IP checks. I'm looking to do this before SS even knows it's being requested.

Comment: @muskie9, link only answers are likely to be deleted, those should be comments. Answers should contain some relevant content.

Comment: @Hailwood, out of curiousity, why do you want to do this before SS boots up? Doing this processing in SilverStripe might take a few more system resources while it is processing but it negates the need for implementing different solutions depending whether you are running an Apache or Nginx setup.

Comment: @Turnerj That's a good point. Call it premature optimization and implement it in SS?

Comment: @Hailwood, yeah I think so in my opinion. You have more to gain from it being in SilverStripe unless you mentioned that your site had a huge amount of traffic attempting to hit the admin page which caused performance problems site wide.